# Understanding 先に in this sentence

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

「新米パパよ。これから大変だろうが頑張れ」
「パパなのにママ友と井戸端会議をする羽目になり、団地で生き残るために、お局におべっかを使わねばならなくなるだろう」
「陰湿な同調圧力に耐え続けた先に待っているのは、子供の反抗期……親父と同じ洗濯機で洗うなと言われるぞ」
So I saw this sentence, but I'm really struggling to understand how 先に being used here.

Is it like "After"? After 陰湿な同調圧力に耐え続けた the thing that awaits you...?

Comment: It's the same as [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41033/45489) though your case is temporal.